# Change string "dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss" into accepted date/time format

Tags: powerbi, date-format

I have a very rare date format dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss that reads in as a string and I want to transform it into a date/time format PowerBI will accept. I managed to change the format into "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss", but now I have to switch the day part with the month.

How can I do this or is there an easier solution to my problem?

Comment: Hi! Welcome. Show us the code of your changing the format into `dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss` so we comment on why it's not working to do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the column of date_time and change the data type from column tools to **Date/time**(pic 1) and after that select the **format**(pic 2) from column tools
[pic_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtQp4.png)

[pic_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUalq.png)